# RadGrid - Client-Side Binding and Caching

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid, radgrid, clientside-caching

I have an asp.net application where I have a radGrid control that displays records from a database. I would like the grid control to do client side caching (paging and sorting). However, I can only find one sample ([Grid - Client-Side Binding and Caching](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/client/caching/defaultcs.aspx)) on Telerik's website, but it uses a webservice as a Databinding location source.

Has anyone had any experience with radGrid, clientside caching displaying data from a database?